# Checking if word is palindrome in Pascal

Tags: pascal, palindrome

I've made program checking if a word is palindrom. I have done this tens of times in Java but here in the `isPalindrom` function `i` never increments and `false` is returned. What is wrong with my program?

```
  program p1;
    var
    n,i:integer;
    slowo:string;

    function isPalindrom(s: string) : boolean;
    var
     dlugosc : integer;
     begin
      dlugosc := Length(s);

      for i:= 1 to dlugosc do
      begin
       writeln(i);  writeln('i = ', i, ' s[i] = ', s[i], 'dlugosc - i = ', dlugosc - i, 's[dlugosc - i] = ', s[dlugosc - i + 1]);
       if s[i] <> s[dlugosc - i] then
        begin
         exit(false);
        end;
      end;
      writeln('-------');
      exit(true);
     end;


    begin
     readln(slowo);
      if isPalindrom(slowo) = TRUE then
       begin
        writeln('is PALINDROM');
       end;
      if  isPalindrom(slowo) = FALSE then
       begin
        writeln('is not PALINDROM');
       end;



     readln;
    end.
```

Comment: you print `'s[dlugosc - i] = ', s[dlugosc - i + 1]);` but check `s[dlugosc - i]` so change it to `s[dlugosc - i +1]`

Comment: Your 'for' loop is too long: it should be 'for i:= 1 to dlugosc div 2'. In other words, you only need compare the first half of the string to the second half. If the value of 'slowo' were 'hannah', then you only need compare the first three letters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
          if s[i] <> s[dlugosc - i] then
```

i is in the range of 1..length(string).  so length(string)-i is in the range of length(string)-1 .. 0.  While, to check a string backwards it should be length(string)..1

So change it to

```
        s[dlugosc-(i-1)]
```

Comment: Thats the way I did it in java but here in Pascal arrays start indexing from 1.

Comment: Yes, subtracting two 1 based indexes cancel each other out, which is the point. Read again, and pay attention to the ranges. Always tracking ranges is the clue to these kinds of problems. Writeln out dlugosc-i if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of jumping out of a 'for' loop very much. You could write your palindrome function more cleanly in the following manner

```
Function Palindrome (const s: string): boolean;
var
 i, len: integer;

begin
 i:= 0;
 len:= length (s);
 result:= true;
 while (i < len div 2) and result do
  begin
   inc (i);
   result:= s[i] = s[len + 1 - i]
  end
end;
```